# change text color of Disabled state of ElevatedButton from ElevatedButton.styleFrom()

Tags: flutter, material-design

I want to change my button text color when Button state is in Disabled mood. By using
onSurface: MyColors.disable, I can change button background disabled state. But button text not changing. How can I solve this issues. Here is my code, I tried

```
class MyTheme {
  MyTheme._();

  static final ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: ShikhoColors.background,
    primaryColor: ShikhoColors.background,
    backgroundColor: ShikhoColors.background,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(style: lightElevatedButtonStyle),
    textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(style: _lightTextButtonStyle),
    outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(style: _lightOutlinedButtonStyle),
    cardTheme: _lightCardStyle,
  );

  static final ButtonStyle lightElevatedButtonStyle = ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    primary: ShikhoColors.blue_main,
    // onSurface: ShikhoColors.disable,
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
    elevation: 0.0,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
    textStyle: TextStyle(color: ShikhoColors.background, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16.0, fontFamily: 'HindSiliguri'),
  );

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work because you set the color to the TextStyle but the color defined by the TextStyle is not used in the button style.

**To change the text color, we need to set the `foregroundColor` property of the `ButtonStyle`.**

see here: [elevated_button src](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/elevated_button.dart#L249)

In your case you need to set the `onPrimary` color property of `ElevatedButton.styleFrom` method. as mentioned [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/elevated_button.dart#L133) it is  used to create a `MaterialStateProperty` `ButtonStyle.foregroundColor`

Comment: can you tell me please in which place, should I use foregroundColor color?

Comment: use `onPrimary` property to refer to a foreground color

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
foreground: Paint()..color= Colors.white
```

to change it to white as an example.